# Cron not running for user

Tags: linux, cron

I want a user (tcff) to run two python scripts at 2am every morning.

I have correctly installed the following crontab for this user:

```
tcff@mymachine> crontab -l

0 2 * * * python /home/tcff/path/to/myscript1.py
0 2 * * * python /home/tcff/path/to/myscript2.py
```

The permissions for each script are:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 tcff tcff  5522 Sep 25 12:41 myscript1.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 tcff tcff  5522 Sep 25 12:41 myscript2.py
```

When I call each script directly they work fine:

```
tcff@mymachine> python /home/tcff/path/to/myscript1.py

[Output as expected]
```

However they are not being run by cron at 2am each morning.

I can't work this out. I am sure I have the permissions correct etc?

Comment: Have a look at the "Debugging crontab" section in http://stackoverflow.com/tags/crontab/info . I bet for full path in `python`.

Comment: you can set up notification emails for failed cron jobs. it contains enough info to debug the problem. most likely, as @fedorqui said, it's a PATH issue.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, indeed, the reason the scripts were not running is because I did not use the full path to the Python binary:

```
0 2 * * * /usr/bin/python /home/tcff/path/to/myscript2.py
```

This is needed because although the shell (bash) has /usr/bin on the PATH the process running cron does not.

Answer (score 0):

First of all give full permission to script file.

```
chmod 777 script_name
```

Also trace the logs of crontab and see what is happening with cronjob here you can see all logs of crontab. May be there is any exception or error.

```
root@localhost:[~]: tail -f /var/log/cron
```